# MacPorts suggests I remove my dylib files. Should I?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, macports

MacPorts documentation mentions the `port diagnose` command to

> "...checks for common issues in the user's environment and reports all issues it finds to the user, along with possible fixes for said problem."

I run it, and get the following message:

```
Error: The installed version of Xcode, none, is not supported by MacPorts.  
For your currently installed system, the following versions of Xcode are supported: 14.3 14.2 14.1
Warning: found dylibs in your /usr/local/lib directory. 
These are known to cause problems. We'd recommend you remove them.
```

The `Error` is because I don't have Xcode currently installed (which I do intend to install), but tell me about the `Warning`: Should I remove the (only) `dylib` file? Here's how `/usr/local/lib` looks like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a “deli file”?

Comment: @Ramhound This autocorrect! :') Fixed.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't installed Xcode yet? I would do that before worrying about the warning. It doesn't say dylib WILL cause problems, only that it can. I recommend fixing your Xcode problem, and then dealing with dylib IF it turns out to be a problem.